# How to resolve broken link in angularJs accessibility?

Tags: html, angularjs, accessibility

In Angular.js I'm improving accessibility using [ngAria](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria).I'm using `ui-sref` so it convert my code from this

```
 <ul style="font-size: 18px">
     <li>
        <a ui-sref="scheduleallocation" >Department Admin DayTimeLocation</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a ui-sref="activityoffering" >ActivityOffering List</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a ui-sref="scheduleassignment" >Schedule Assignment</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

to this

```
<ul style="font-size: 18px">
   <li>
       <a ui-sref="scheduleallocation" href="#/scheduleallocation">Department Admin DayTimeLocation</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a ui-sref="activityoffering" href="#/activityoffering">ActivityOffering List</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a ui-sref="scheduleassignment" href="#/scheduleassignment//">Schedule Assignment</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

it added # in href so that's why getting following error in accessibility. How to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: what's your hash-bang? you might need `#!/` instead of `#/`

Comment: I changed it to ! But still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to using html5mode with angularJs's $location service.

When you have html5Mode enabled, the # character will no longer be used in your urls. Using the # symbol is easier, because it requires no server side configuration. Html5Mode uses the browsers history API, and does not require the # character - the url looks much nicer, but it also requires server side rewrites.

Using html5mode will change your link from
   `href="#/scheduleallocation"` to `href="/scheduleallocation"`

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location for more info on using html5mode.